# WPF Как реализовать асинхронность

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется команда, которая по выделенной книге находит студентов, которым выдана книга.

```
if (SelectItem is Book book)
            FormSource = from st in students
                         from fm in forms
                         where fm.IDBook == book.ID
                               && fm.IDForm == st.ID
                         select new
                         {
                             st.ID,
                             st.FullName,
                             st.Group,
                             fm.DateOfIssue
                         };
```

`SelectItem` это выбранный элемент в datagrid книг.

`students` и `forms` это `ObservableCollection` загруженная предварительно из базы данных

```
_library.Students.Load();

_library.Forms.Load();
```

`FormSource` это ItemSource DataGrid на котором отображаются студенты, которым выдана данная книга

Так как у меня будет много студентов и формуляров для них, нужно данную задачу выполнять асинхронно. Желательно, чтобы `FormSource` обновлялся постепенно. И ещё нужно как-то отменять запущенную задачу при повторном выполнение команды.

Полный [проект](https://github.com/flash1371/DigitalLibrary) на GitHub. Критика приветствуется.

Comment: `нужно данную задачу выполнять асинхронно` что в вашем понимании это означает?

Comment: Чтобы выполнялось не в UI потоке, то есть не блокировало интерфейс

Comment: так оберните нужный вам код в `Task.Run(()=>{....})` и он будет на пуле потоков выполняться

Comment: А как быть с отменной задачи при запуске новой  и постепенным обновлением FormSource?

Comment: используйте `CancellationToken` для отмены операции